# How to obtain solution to constants "c_n" from Fourier's trick?

Tags: fourier-analysis, complex-integration, quantum-mechanics, wave-equation

[how is the answer for c_n in the red box obtained from the line above?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BeFy.jpg)

Going through the example problem in the image, I don't understand how the answer in the red box was obtained. Mathematica does not return anything similar. How can I obtain the answer that is shown in the image? Further, how could I do this on Mathematica?

Comment: It's by actually doing the integration for $c_n$ with the $\psi$ that they chose at the top. This can be done in a number of ways including integration by parts.

Comment: What do you get when you try evaluating it in Mathematica? I get a very similar expression.

Comment: in mathematica, the infinite well width 'a' remains in the solution when integrating from 0 to a. Where does it go in the image solution? And how would I perform the integration by parts for this case?

Comment: My guess is you're getting output like first one [here](https://snag.gy/FV9JgS.jpg). Mathematica doesn't know if sqrt(a^2) is a or -a, so it leaves it unsimplified. In the second one, i've told it a is positive and it's able to divide out all appearances of a.

Comment: ah excellent. And then to reduce the trig components, do i factor out -2? Or is there some trig identity involved in reducing the answer to whats shown in the original image? (cos(0) - cos(n*Pi)

Comment: First of all, $\sin(n \pi) = 0$ for all integer $n$ (Mathematica doesn't know n is an integer, so it doesn't simplify this, [you could tell it it's an integer though](https://snag.gy/zRBSm8.jpg)), then factor out the -2 and notice $1 = \cos 0$ to get the form in the image you linked.

Comment: awesome. thanks for the help man